# Using public key in asymmetric encryption with X.509 certificates

Tags: c#, x509certificate, private-key

Sometimes ago I've read an article about using asymmetric keys like public and private keys to send data securely. What I've understood was that the **server** has 1 key **(private key)** that it use to encrypt data and all **clients** use the second key **(public key)** to decrypt it.

Now how should I expect to receive the key and how should I work with?

If I receive a Certificate from the server, wouldn't it contain both public and private keys?!

```
X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
var cert = GetCertificate(certStore);
var privatekey= cert.PrivateKey;
var publicKey= cert.PublicKey;
```

Is it possbile to remove the private key from the certificate? How? and how can I understand if the certificate has the private key?

Comment: The encrypt key and de-crypt keys must be the same.  The encryption/decryption algorithm uses a key that is composed of two pieces.  One that is part of application (private key) and the second which is unique for each message/connection (public key).

Comment: In public key cryptography you encrypt with server _public_ key, and server decrypts with its private key. So server distributes its certificate (without private key of course) which is available for all clients.

Comment: The certificate never contains the private key. Only the C# internal structures group them together (if the private key is present).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I receive a Certificate from the server, wouldn't it contain both public and private keys?!

No, not necessarily.

There are two different ways of obtaining the certificate

- PKCS#7/PEM - the file usually contains only the public part of the certificate
- PKCS#12/PFX - the store contains certificates with private keys

> Is it possbile to remove the private key from the certificate?

By exporting it to a format that lets you store only the public part of the certificate.

Open a web browser, navigate to any site that uses SSL.

Now click the lock icon and, from there, the certificate information. What you have at the client side (in the browser) is the certificate **without** the private key. You can save it and even import into the system cert store but still without the private key.

> and how can I understand if the certificate has the private key?

If you load it with your C# code, accessing the `HasPrivateKey` property will be `true` only for certs with private keys available.

Answer (score 2):

First a little bit of clarification:

In [Public-key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) the **public key** is used to **encrypt** the data and the **private key** is used (by the server) to **decrypt** the data.

The owner of the private key stores private key and only shares a public key.
Any certificate from a server should contain **only** a **public key**.
(It would be a big security issue if the certificate contains the private Key. You could decrypt the messages from any other user)

To check if the cerificate has a private key you can use the [HasPrivateKey-Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.hasprivatekey(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
cert.HasPrivateKey;
```

And to get a certificate with only the public key you can use:

```
byte[] bytes = cert.Export(X509ContentType.Cert);
var publicCert = new X509Certificate2(bytes);
```